# How to avoid NA columns in dcast() output?

Tags: r, na, reshape2

How can I *avoid* `NA` columns in `dcast()` output from the `reshape2` package?

In this dummy example the `dcast()` output will include an `NA` column:

```
require(reshape2)
data(iris)
iris[ , "Species2"] <- iris[ , "Species"]
iris[ 2:7, "Species2"] <- NA
(x <- dcast(iris, Species ~ Species2, value.var = "Sepal.Width", 
            fun.aggregate = length))
##     Species setosa versicolor virginica NA
##1     setosa     44          0         0  6
##2 versicolor      0         50         0  0
##3  virginica      0          0        50  0
```

For a somewhat similar usecase, `table()` does have an option that allows to avoid this:

```
table(iris[ , c(5,6)], useNA = "ifany")  ##same output as from dcast()
##            Species2
##Species      setosa versicolor virginica <NA>
##  setosa         44          0         0    6
##  versicolor      0         50         0    0
##  virginica       0          0        50    0
table(iris[ , c(5,6)], useNA = "no")  ##avoid NA columns
##            Species2
##Species      setosa versicolor virginica
##  setosa         44          0         0
##  versicolor      0         50         0
##  virginica       0          0        50
```

Does `dcast()` have a similar option that removes `NA` columns in the output? How can I avoid getting `NA` columns? (This function has a number of rather cryptic options that are sternly documented and that I cannot quite grasp...)

Comment: You could do `dcast(na.omit(iris), Species ~ Species2, value.var = "Sepal.Width")`, but this isn't very general solution if you are interested in some other columns too.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Indeed. I was aware of `na.omit(iris)`-like solutions, but I was looking for a different approach. I didn't include this requirement in the question to avoid making it too confusing...

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's intended behaviour so you need to consciously remove missing data (instead of doing that accidentally). I would solve it by selecting the data first, so `iris[!is.na(iris$Species2),]`.

Comment: @Heroka how would that be better than `na.omit`?

Comment: @David if it's only NA's in a certain column that need to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I was able to get around it:

```
iris[is.na(iris)] <- 'None'

x <- dcast(iris, Species ~ Species2, value.var="Sepal.Width", fun.aggregate = length)

x$None <- NULL
```

The idea is that you replace all the NAs with 'None', so that dcast creates a column called 'None' rather than 'NA'. Then, you can just delete that column in the next step if you don't need it.

Comment: Can you format your code as code, to make it easier to read? (Indent 4 spaces, or use the `{}` button.) Also, please add an explanation so that others can better understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I've found, which I'm not positively unhappy with, is based on the dropping NA values approach suggested in the comments. It leverages the `subset` argument in `dcast()` along with `.()` from `plyr`:

```
require(plyr)
(x <- dcast(iris, Species ~ Species2, value.var = "Sepal.Width",
            fun.aggregate = length, subset = .(!is.na(Species2))))
##     Species setosa versicolor virginica
##1     setosa     44          0         0
##2 versicolor      0         50         0
##3  virginica      0          0        50
```

For my particular purpose (within a custom function) the following works better:

```
(x <- dcast(iris, Species ~ Species2, value.var = "Sepal.Width", 
            fun.aggregate = length, subset = .(!is.na(get("Species2")))))
##     Species setosa versicolor virginica
##1     setosa     44          0         0
##2 versicolor      0         50         0
##3  virginica      0          0        50
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the NA column of the output and then make it NULL. (This works for me).

```
require(reshape2)
data(iris)
iris[ , "Species2"] <- iris[ , "Species"]
iris[ 2:7, "Species2"] <- NA

(x <- dcast(iris, Species ~ Species2, value.var = "Sepal.Width", 
            fun.aggregate = length)) 

setnames(x , c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica", "newname"))

x$newname <- NULL
```

Answer (score -2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
iris %>%
  filter(!is.na(Species2)) %>%
  group_by(Species, Species2) %>%
  summarize(freq = n()) %>%
  spread(Species2, freq)
```

Comment: All said and done, I would rather a `dcast()`-based solution, if possible.

Comment: Why exactly are people downvoting this answer?

Comment: @MikeWise I don't know, but I suspect because it proposes an alternative instead of attempting to address the issue within the constraints of the question (i.e. the `dcast()` function). I do agree though that downvotes without *any* explanations is one of the most negative and counter-productive, community-wise, hehaviors around SE...

Comment: It seems like a valuable answer to me, though it would have been nice if he had added a sentence or two explaining it.