# R: column binding

Tags: r

I have the following two tables I'd like to combine:

```
> toytable
   id sid_set
1:  1 a, b, c
2:  2    c, b
3:  3       a
4:  4    d, b

> tdf3
   value
id  a b c d
  1 1 1 1 0
  2 0 1 1 0
  3 1 0 0 0
  4 0 1 0 1

> class(tdf3)
[1] "table"
> class(toytable)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

Ideally, I want a column binding that results in a `data.table` of the following form:

```
id a b c d
1  1 1 1 0
2  0 1 1 0
3  1 0 0 0
4  0 1 0 1
```

I thought this should be a straightforward `cbind`, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I have tried:

```
cbind(tdf3, toytable[, 'id']) # my initial thought
cbind(toytable[, 'id'], tdf3) # just switched position of my args, not expecting any difference
cbind(data.frame(tdf3), data.frame(toytable[, 'id'])) # thought there might be an unusual treatment of data.table objects
```

with the following result (or some variation of it):

```
   id value Freq id
1   1     a    1  1
2   2     a    0  2
3   3     a    1  3
4   4     a    0  4
5   1     b    1  1
6   2     b    1  2
7   3     b    0  3
8   4     b    1  4
9   1     c    1  1
10  2     c    1  2
11  3     c    0  3
12  4     c    0  4
13  1     d    0  1
14  2     d    0  2
15  3     d    0  3
16  4     d    1  4
```

I think the issue is because `tdf3` is a `table` object. I tried converting it to a `data.table` object, but it results in a weird representation:

```
> data.table(tdf3)
    id value N
 1:  1     a 1
 2:  2     a 0
 3:  3     a 1
 4:  4     a 0
 5:  1     b 1
 6:  2     b 1
 7:  3     b 0
 8:  4     b 1
 9:  1     c 1
10:  2     c 1
11:  3     c 0
12:  4     c 0
13:  1     d 0
14:  2     d 0
15:  3     d 0
16:  4     d 1
```

Any leads or pointers to examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your description , I think you need string dummies , then you can using 
`concat.split.expanded` from `splitstackshape`

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 concat.split.expanded(df, "sid_set", type = "character", drop = TRUE,fill = 0)
  id sid_set_a sid_set_b sid_set_c sid_set_d
1  1         1         1         1         0
2  2         0         1         1         0
3  3         1         0         0         0
4  4         0         1         0         1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution with melt and dcast from data.table

```
library(data.table)
toytable <- setDT(toytable)
toytable[,sid_set := as.character(sid_set)]
toytablestr <- cbind(id = toytable[,id],toytable[,tstrsplit(sid_set,"[,]")])
plouf <- melt(toytablestr,measure.vars = patterns("^V"))[is.na(value),value := "None"]
plop <- dcast(plouf,id~value)[,None := NULL][]
```

I used first the funciton `tstrsplit` to have the different letters, that I bind with the ids.

After, I melt and use the work around described  here [How to avoid NA columns in dcast() output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931473/how-to-avoid-na-columns-in-dcast-output) to get rid of the NA column name when going back to wide format with dacast

```
> plop
   id a b c d
1:  1 1 1 1 0
2:  2 0 1 1 0
3:  3 1 0 0 0
4:  4 0 1 0 1
```