# data.table::dcast long to wide data while ignoring NA-Category?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to transform my data from long to wide after some joins, resulting in a few `NA`s in the data provided.
Unfortunately, these `NA`s are also present in the richt-hand side (*RHS*), which defines the newly added columns via the transformation.

Consider this example:

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id=c(1,2,1,2,3,4),
           group = c("A","A","B","B",NA,NA),
           values = c(7,8,9,10,NA,NA))


dt_wide <- dcast(dt,
                 id ~ group,
                 value.var = c("values"))
```

In the data, rows 5 and 6 do not have any group or associated value:

```r
   id group values
1:  1     A      7
2:  2     A      8
3:  1     B      9
4:  2     B     10
5:  3  <NA>     NA
6:  4  <NA>     NA
```

if there is an associated value, a group does exist, therefore:  (`group` == `NA`) => (`value` == `NA`)

the transformed dataframe wrongly considers `NA` as its own group in the `group`- column, which results in the following wide data table:

```
   id NA  A  B
1:  1 NA  7  9
2:  2 NA  8 10
3:  3 NA NA NA
4:  4 NA NA NA
```

I would not prefer to build a possible buggy workaround where i retroactively delete the NA column by name or values (as it might handle different colnames and columns later in production).

Is there a way to tell `dcast` to ignore the NAs in group and not make an extra column out of it, while preserving all rows in the transformed table?

Like this:

```r
   id  A  B
1:  1  7  9
2:  2  8 10
3:  3 NA NA
4:  4 NA NA
```

Comment: Related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931473/how-to-avoid-na-columns-in-dcast-output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tricky, but seems to work:

```
dcast(dt,
      id ~ ifelse(is.na(group),unique(na.omit(dt$group)),group),
      value.var = c("values"))

Key: <id>
      id     A     B
   <num> <num> <num>
1:     1     7     9
2:     2     8    10
3:     3    NA    NA
4:     4    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to prevent `dcast` from doing that. I'd just filter them out afterwards:

```
dt_wide[, names(dt_wide) != "NA", with = FALSE]
```

**Output:**

```
   id  A  B
1:  1  7  9
2:  2  8 10
3:  3 NA NA
4:  4 NA NA
```